# Arabic font for Listing

Tags: listings, arabic, xml

Currently, I am using Listings package in order to insert my XML text in the document.

For example the code:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
   <Product Title="نوکیا" Type="گوشی">
\end{lstlisting}
```

The problem in here is that **Listings** does not support **Arabic** font. As a result 'نوکیا' and 'گوشی' can not be shown.
Is there any solution to make Arabic font be supported by the Listings package?

Comment: Which TeX format do you use: pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTex, or something else? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico I use XeLaTex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of solution is this. first define your listingstyle like this before `\begin{document}`

**If your main Language is persian then:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\lstdefinestyle{MyXML}{
      language=XML,
      escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
      morekeywords={encoding,
        xs:schema,xs:element,xs:complexType,xs:sequence,xs:attribute}
}
```

then in your listing code use this code

```
مقاله من فارسی می‌باشد
\begin{latin}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=MyXML]
   <Product Title="%*\rl{نوکیا}*)" Type="%*\rl{گوشی}*)">
\end{lstlisting}
\end{latin}
انتهای مقاله
```

here is my output

[image]

**If your main language is English then:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{farsi}

\newfontfamily\farsifont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Scheherazade}


\lstdefinestyle{MyXML}{
      language=XML,
      escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
      morekeywords={encoding,
        xs:schema,xs:element,xs:complexType,xs:sequence,xs:attribute}
}
```

then in your Article:

```
My Article is In English Language

\begin{lstlisting}[style=MyXML]
    <Product Title="%*\textfarsi{نوکیا}*)" Type="%*\textfarsi{گوشی}*)">
\end{lstlisting}

End of Article
```

and the output

[image]

Comment: I get this error while I am trying to compile: Environment latin undefined. what is the problem?

Comment: @Pedram your article is in Persian ? or English ? if your main language is English just don't use `\begin{latin}` and `\end{latin}`

Comment: Thanks for your help. My article in is English. There are only a few cases that I use Persian as the value of an attribute in my XML. I did exactly what you said. But I did not get the answer. Take a look at this picture: http://www.4shared.com/photo/KOVxBes-ce/1__1_.html

Comment: @Pedram is this working now ?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's easy to create the document with `arabtex` package. Arabic word/sentence is typed between `\<` and `>`. So, we need to define `escapeinside` character for `listings` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{escapeinside=``}

\begin{document}
    \setcode{utf8}

    \begin{lstlisting}
       <Product Title="`\<نوکیا>`" Type="`\<گوشی>`">
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]